# Ошибка при трансяции потока через хромкаст cast_sender.js

Tags: javascript, cast, chromecast

Добавляю хромкаст согласно [туториалу](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender/integrate).

После добавления кнопки хромкаста, нажимаю её, выбираю доступное устройство из сети, идёт подключение. В браузере виден статус "Идёт трансляция" , по факту ничего не происходит, кроме возникновения следующей ошибки в консоли:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadMedia' of null
```

**Код:**

```
    cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().setOptions({
        receiverApplicationId: '111111',
        autoJoinPolicy: chrome.cast.AutoJoinPolicy.ORIGIN_SCOPED
    });


    var currentMediaURL =
        'https://.....';
    var contentType = 'mp4';

            var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(currentMediaURL,contentType);
            var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
            console.log('Ниже переменная -mediaInfo ');
            console.log(mediaInfo);
            console.log('Ниже переменная -request ');
            console.log(request);

            var castSession = cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
             console.log('Ниже переменная -castSession ');
            console.log(castSession);

    castSession.loadMedia(request).then(
        function () {
            console.log('Load succeed');
        },
        function (errorCode) {
            console.log('Error code: ' + errorCode);
        });
```

Тестирование кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю почему-то не отправляться ссылка на поток.
Есть интересный вопрос, почему ссылка на поток ложиться в переменную `contentid` хотя есть переменная `contentUrl` ?